# Get a type from a Union based on string property

Tags: typescript

Given the type:

```
type Invitation =
  | {
      __typename?: 'ClientInvitation'
      email: string
      hash: string
      organizationName: string
    }
  | {
      __typename?: 'ExpertInvitation'
      email: string
      hash: string
      expertName: string
    }
```

how can I infer one of the types?

For example:

```
type ClientInvitation = SomeTypeUtil['ClientInvitation']
```

should make `ClientInvitation` have:

```
    {
      __typename?: 'ClientInvitation'
      email: string
      hash: string
      organizationName: string
    }
```

Comment: Do you really mean to use brackets ([indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)) like `SomeTypeUtil['ClientInvitation']`? Or would a normal generic type utility like `SomeTypeUtil<'ClientInvitation'>` be acceptable? [You can actually do it either way](https://tsplay.dev/wR5L7W), but it's a little weird to expect that indexed access would be possible.  Is this just a typo?

Comment: @jcalz I don't really care :) Do you want to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use [a mapped type with renamed keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) like this:

```
type InvitationMap = { [T in Invitation as NonNullable<T['__typename']>]: T }
```

Here we are iterating the type `T` over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of `Invitation`.  For each such member `T` we want the property *value* to be `T`, and we want the property *key* to be the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of `T`'s `__typename` property.  That would just be `T['__typename']` using [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), but that doesn't quite work.  Because the `__typename` property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), the property type will include `undefined` (like `'ClientInvitation' | undefined` or `'ExpertInvitation' | undefined`).  To remove `undefined` quickly we can use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype).

Let's look at the IntelliSense quick info for the `InvitationMap` type:

```
/* type InvitationMap = {
    ClientInvitation: {
        __typename?: "ClientInvitation" | undefined;
        email: string;
        hash: string;
        organizationName: string;
    };
    ExpertInvitation: {
        __typename?: "ExpertInvitation" | undefined;
        email: string;
        hash: string;
        expertName: string;
    };
} */
```

Now that we have `InvitationMap`, we can just index into it with the desired key:

```
type ClientInvitation = InvitationMap['ClientInvitation'];
/* type ClientInvitation = {
    __typename?: "ClientInvitation" | undefined;
    email: string;
    hash: string;
    organizationName: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)